# Facing issue in making server side pagination work with MUI Datagrid for my use case

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datagrid, react-props, mui-datatable

I am trying to pass only **page** and **pageSize** from **App.tsx**  => Parent component
and change **onPageChange** and **onPageSizeChange** accordingly at **demo.tsx** => child component
is it possible to make server side pagination work in the given sandbox?

[My CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/serverpaginationgrid-demo-mui-x-forked-02q143?file=/demo.tsx)

[This is the docs of MUI server side pagination](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/pagination/#server-side-pagination)